# How behave alternate icons feature regarding app updates?

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode6

I'm currently using [the alternate icons feature](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring_your_app_to_use_alternate_app_icons) in my app, it works fine. I have a small question regarding of how behaves this feature regarding a possible app update.

For example:

1. The user set an alternate icon from my app
2. The app is now using the alternate icon
3. A new version of my app is released to the App Store
4. The user updates the app

The question is:

Is the alternate icon feature provided by the SDK is using a storage system such as `UserDefaults` or something else to remember that an alternate icon has been selected, or do I have to programmatically do it and check it after each new version ?

I didn't find anything relative to this in the documentation.

Thanks